# date function not correctly returning date

Tags: plugins, php, functions

This code is being used to generate the date of a post in wordpress:

```
<span class="the_date">Posted: <?php echo get_the_time('F d, Y'); ?></span>
```

However it is not resutning the date, it is returning the text instead:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is peculiar... How is the loop for there posts set up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the time to the user you should use the_time(); template tag instead.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Comment: Please explain why _that_ would solve problem. `the_time()` is just a wrapper for `get_the_time()`, so you have to be very creative. :)